# Index method for string variable, inside conditional loop, not returning desired results

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
text = "iiiiiiWiiiiiiWWiiiiW"
for char in text:
    if (char == "W"):
        z = text.index(char)
        print z
```

I'm having a problem with the above code. I'm not getting my desired response.
I am receiving:

```
>>>9
>>>9
>>>9
>>>9
```

...instead of getting something like...

```
>>>9
>>>16
>>>17
>>>22
```

This is confusing me :( please help and thanks :)

Comment: I tried different variations of code and it seems as if there is no changing the z variable.

Comment: It always helps to read the docs for built-in methods: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.index

Answer (score 1):

`text.index('W')` will always return the position of the first occurence of `'W'` in `text`. You could do it like that:

```
text = "iiiiiiWiiiiiiWWiiiiW"
for pos, char in enumerate(text):
    if char == "W":
        print pos
```